# Is it Compound sentence? What are the two main clauses?

Tags: grammar

Raj is not only brave but also clever.
Is it Compound sentence? What are the two main clauses?

Comment: No, it's not a compound sentence. "Not only brave" and "also clever" form a coordination of two adjective phrases, not two main clauses: _Raj is [not only brave] but [also clever]_.